# ERROR: Streaming jar not found

Tags: java, hadoop

Whenever I am running the following code to download a .csv file to my local system from a distributed file system (hdfs), I am getting the following error

> ERROR: Streaming jar not found

The command I executed is

```
dumbo cat <hdfs path for .csv file> -hadoop $HADOOP_INSTALL > <.csv file path in local system>
```

I want to get the .csv file to open in libre-calc. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To access files from HDFS, you have various options. From the command-line, there are two options:

- Accessing HDFS via a NFS mounted drive (Then you can use the commands as with every other file that is on a mounted drive with a linux filesystem)
- Using HDFS commands.

In your case, the following should do the job

> hdfs dfs -get hdfs-path localpath

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The hdfs dfs -get command does not result into a file of .csv format which is readable through MS Excel or open office Libre-calc.